# how I can resize the height of a widget inside a layout

Tags: python, pyqt

If you notice the geometry property you can't access to it and change the values:

[image: 1]

I want to resize the height of a button inside a layout, how I can fix it?

Comment: Change the *vertical* `sizePolicy` property of the button to `Preferred`. Also, you should set a main layout, not drag a layout from the widget box: those are supposed to be added as *nested* layouts inside the main layout of a widget. See how to properly [use layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Answer (score 0):

set **sizePolicy** (Horizontal and Vertical) Fixed, for the **minimumSize** you can change **Width** and **Height** as you want/need, see attached image for more clarifications.

[image]

Also, if you want to adjust the size of the button to the Layout did what I do in this image **(Lay out -> Adjust size)**:

[image]